# How to show local notifications on lock screen by default in flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, android-notifications, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

Is there a way to show local notifications on the lockscreen by default? I've added the permissions but it's only showing up when I manually allow it in settings. By default it'll only use vibration and sound and stay tucked in the notifications drawer

Here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

I'm using my notification as a reminder so need the user to be alerted immediately

```
var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'CHANNEL 1',
      'Notifications',
      "Reminders",
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
      enableLights: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      showWhen: true,
      visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flutter local notifications package...
[flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Comment: Try using Firebase_messaging...It would be easy to achieve.